# Pen pressure not working anymore in Photoshop or other app

Tags: windows, adobe-photoshop, graphics-tablet, pen

Pen pressure for graphic tablets is not working in Photoshop, nor in any other Windows app.

1. Windows Ink is activated in all the instances, drivers are updated in all the devices (Wacom Intuos Pro, Huion Kamwas Pro 16);
2. Pen Pressure stopped to work abruptly from one launch of Photoshop to another (nothing installed in between);
3. Photoshop is not detecting any pen pressure for the brushes. Also, Photoshop preferences were reinitialized;

Sys info in the following link:

[System info](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16FYF_4rxSMxQE-DnzOv1jfEJIdZdp8Fn/view)

Comment: What is the make and model of your graphics tablet?

Answer (score 0):

According to your own post, this is not connected to Photoshop,
but is a general problem on this one tablet (what model?).

This can be either a software/driver problem or hardware.

If this is hardware, this is not something we can help with,

To check if Windows Update switched the touch driver, go into Settings,
click Update & Security, Windows Update, ensure you are in the
Windows Update section, then click on View update history.

Check if some update happened on the day that this started happening,
or the day before.

If that is the case, go to Device Manager, find the touch device, right-click,
Properties. In the Driver tab, try to click Roll Back Driver (if not disabled).